# Impact of number of probes vs number of probe sequences on the performance of open addressing sheme

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, hash

The book [Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC) analyzes [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) schemes by making the assumption of uniform hashing which basically says that the probe sequence of each key is equally likely to be any of m! permutations of <0,1,2,...m-1> . The book then introduces three schemes :

1. Linear probing
2. Quadratic probing
3. Double hashing

It says that all these aforementioned techniques guarantee that  is a permutation of <<0,1,2,...m-1> for each key k . But none of them fulfills the assumption of uniform hashing, however , since none of them is capable of generating more than m^2different probe sequences . Double hashing has the greatest number of probe sequences and seems to give the best results .

Why do we want a maximum number of probe sequences ? Do we not get the best performance when the probe sequence is least ? I am sure there is some fundamentals that I am missing here . I think I am getting confused between probes and probe sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea that here is that we need a function `f` that maps large numbers (or could be `String`s that are being represented essentially by numbers) into smaller numbers that are more manageable.
These smaller numbers are typically used directly as indexes in an array so that we can obtain the contant access time `O(1)` guaranteed by `HashTable`.
This function `f` is typically the hashfunction.
Now the problem is that since we go from a larger space to a smaller space, we are bound to have collisions (which affect our access time guarantees).
For how we deal with collisions (assuming that we have already decided on a hash function to use) there are various approaches, and you mention 3 of them.

`Linear Probing` is the simplest collision resolution strategy whereby we essentially search the array sequentially until we find an empty cell. Although this is trivial to implement it is not efficient as it results in clustering of the data in our `hashtable`.
To sum up the performance degrades due to the fact that both items with the same hash collide but also items that *collide in alternative location*.

`Quadratic Probing` tries to improve on `Linear` by trying to occupy cells further than the original probing point. Although it improves much on `Linear Probing` it introduces secondary clustering (elements that have the same hash probe also the same alternative locations in the array).

`Double Hashing` improves further on `Quadratic Probing` and theoriticaly (I think) it is supposed to have the same number or probes as linear.

> Double hashing has the greatest number of probe sequences and seems to
>   give the best results ...   Why do we want a maximum number of probe
>   sequences ?

Yes theoritically it is better that `Quadratic`. What is meant here IMO is that the locations to probe are furthest away so eliminating collisions among elements of same hash or different hash *in alternative location (than original bucket)*